# Dialog jquery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, dialog

My dialog doesn't show, can u help me?

Html :

```
<li><a href="#" id="chopen">Character</a></li>
<div id="character" title="Character">
    <p>you charcter here</p>
</div>
```

and js :

```
$(function () {
    $("#character").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "blind"
    });
    $("#chopen").click(function () {
        $("#character").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
});
```

ofc all in document.ready

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/CodingDawg/CLJHG/1/

Comment: You're including jQuery and jQuery-UI, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you already install plugin jquery UI ?

if not yet, You must install plugin jquery UI version, because jquery dialog dependency to jquery UI library. as below :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and also able to download this library from [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/)